# Aurelia MVC Set up having issues with 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, aurelia

I started using aurelia framework with Vs2015 and MVC.

**Below is my implementation process**

1. Created new project with MVC in VS 2015.
2. Copied all files except wwwroot inside skelton-es2016-asp.net5 from aurelia-skelton project from github.
3. Later added all bootstarp and jquery plugin inside script and added in bundleconfig.cs
4. Open command prompt from folder and `jspm install`,

   Then `jspm install aurelia-framework`,

   Then `jspm install aurelia-bootstrapper`
5. Finally attached to IIS and browse.

**But I am getting 404 not found with core-js@1.2.6 js.** Below is my screen.

[image]

**Also below is my VS structure**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed `core-js` through JSPM. Add the dependency to your `package.json`.

**package.json**

```
"jspm": {
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.2.6"
  }
}
```

Then type `jspm install` in the command line.

Comment: if this answer works for your, upvote and accept please